# Is it possible to have a self-describing XML instance document that includes it's schema within the same instance document?

Tags: xml, xsd

All the examples I have encountered usually demonstrate referencing a separate schema document from the instance document. For various reasons, I would rather carry the schema and instance xml in a single (same) document. It seems intuitive to me, with namespaces of course, that should be possible.